# How to disable all emoticons in android keyboard

Tags: android, android-webview, android-keypad, emoticons

I want to disable all the emoticons i.e smileys, buildings etc in my android keyboard programmatically so that user is unable to see them or enter them. My application is webview based and I have added this line to my webview layout but no use

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
```